# nginx location regex with proxypass

Tags: regular-expression, nginx

I am quite new to nginx so excuse me in advance if I am asking something obvious.

What I am trying to do is to proxypass to another server a request that comes to my nginx server in the form of:

```
http://mysite/locationA/results?-variablerandomtexthere-test=true
```

The way tried to do this was:

```
  location ~* ^/locationA/results\?(.*)test=true$ {
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all ;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_pass   http://myserver.org/ ;
proxy_redirect off;
}
```

The above example doesn't work and with a bit of Googling I found out that you cannot use regex on location with proxy_pass.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve this by doing the following:

```
 location / {

 if ($arg_test ~ "true") {
    set $gotoserver 1;
    }
if ($uri ~* "(queries|results)") {
   set $gotoserver  "${gotoserver}1" ;
    }
if ($gotoserver = 11) {
proxy_pass http://myserver.org ;
    }
}
```